# Could not locate the assembly "CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine,

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am making changes to the current vb.net application and i have moved it from the server to my computer running windows 10.

After finishing adding new module when rebuilding these errors are coming up...please help

> Warning   1   Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the
> assembly "CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on
> disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get
> compilation errors.   Smart Systems

Comment: iam making changes to the current vb.net application and i have moved it from the server to my computer running windows 10. after finishing adding new module when rebuilding these errors are coming up..please help

Comment: Did you installed same version of crystal report on the Visual Studio of the new machine ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that you recently moved the application to your computer, do you have the Crystal related .dlls installed on your local environment?  Check your project references and see the path it is looking for.